# 403-ERR_BAD_REQUEST: Request faild with status code 403 when I using get and post for React-Chat-Engine api

Tags: reactjs, api, axios, http-status-code-403, react-chat-engine

please tell me what I did wrong and why I have 403 axiosError?
I am using React v17 and axios v0.27.2 and react-chat-engine v1.11.23 . how can I fix this problem?

**here is my imports**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { ChatEngine } from "react-chat-engine";
import axios from "axios";

// Contexts
import { AuthContext } from "../contexts/AuthContextProvider";
```

**and this is main code**

```
const Chats = () => {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const user = useContext(AuthContext);
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!user) {
            navigate("/");
            return;
        }
        axios
            .get("https://api.chatengine.io/users/me/", {
                headers: {
                    "Project-ID": "6e1e7008-716b-4141-a15c-836f05f720dd",
                    "User-Name": user.email,
                    "User-Secret": user.uid,
                },
            })
            .then(() => {
                setLoading(false);
            })
            .catch(() => {
                let formdata = new FormData();
                formdata.append("email", user.email);
                formdata.append("username", user.email);
                formdata.append("secret", user.uid);
                getFile(user.photoURL).then((avatar) => {
                    formdata.append("avatar", avatar, avatar.name);
                    axios
                        .post("https://api.chatengine.io/users/", formdata, {
                            headers: {
                                "private-key":
                                    "8094d378-e224-4558-97bf-35ca877f8f8e",
                            },
                        })
                        .then(() => setLoading(false))
                        .catch((error) => console.log(error));
                });
            });
    }, [user, navigate]);

    const getFile = async (url) => {
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const data = await response.blob();
        return new File([data], "userPhoto.jpg", { type: "image/jpeg" });
    };

    if (!user || loading) return "Loading...";

    return (
        <div>
            <ChatEngine
                height="calc(100vh - 50px)"
                projectID="6e1e7008-716b-4141-a15c-836f05f720dd"
                userName={user.email}
                userSecret={user.uid}
            />
        </div>
    );
};

export default Chats;
```

Also when I click on api Urls, opens a page and write HTTP 403 Forbidden.
Generally i do not have access the api and chat engine.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

To make a connection to the api server you need a private key that is placed at your `API Keys` section in your project dashboard. Then use it as `axios` header. You can see the example from the official POST example [here](https://chatengine.io/docs/react/v1/backend)

```
headers: {
   'PRIVATE-KEY': '{{private_key}}'
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with the same code. I fixed it by changing the VPN service. Please check your private key and test with other VPN services.